# Gulp.dest() when using multiple globs

Tags: gulp, gulp-less, gulp-rename

I'm having trouble with a glob and gulp.dest(). My task looks like this

```
return gulp.src('./clients/*/assets/less/*.less',{ base: process.cwd() })
    .pipe(less({
        paths:[path.join(__dirname, 'less')]
    }).on('error', function(err){
        gutil.log(err);
        this.emit('end');
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
        cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(function(file){
        return path.normalize(path.join(file.path, '../css'));
    }));
```

If my path for example was `./clients/my-client/assets/less/style.less` the path ends up being `./clients/my-client/assets/css/my-client/assets/less/css
I tried using a rename function like

```
.pipe(rename(function (path) {
    path.dirname = '';
}))
```

Before but all that did was put the file at `./clients/css/style.css`

The desired directory should be `./clients/my-client/assets/less/style.css` and thought this would all be rather easy, and perhaps it is, but I'm really struggling. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this isn't a great solution, considering how it could theoretically go wrong, but it worked for me for now.

I used `gulp-rename` to simply replace `less` for `css` in the `dirname`.

```
var src = './clients/*/assets/less/*.less';

return gulp.src(src,{base: './clients/'})
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(less({
        paths:[path.join(__dirname, 'less')]
    }).on('error', function(err){
        gutil.log(err);
        this.emit('end');
    }))
    .pipe(cleanCSS({debug: true}, function(details) {
        console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.originalSize);
        console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.minifiedSize);
    }))
    .pipe(filesize())
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
        path.dirname = path.dirname.replace(/less/i,'css');
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./clients/'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: "Style compressed", onLast: true}) );
```